# Window buttons not visible on Win10 with Infragistics

Tags: c#, windows, infragistics

In the application I cannot see the Minimize/Maximize/Close buttons on the main form on Win10.

The only way to to this is to add:

```cs
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
```

But this results in not being able to resize the window when it's not maximized, which is not a nice situation.

Did anyone encounter such a thing? What was the solution if so?

Thanks&Regards,

Erdi

Comment: Is ControlBox set to true??

Comment: For the ControlBox property to have any effect, you must also set the form's FormBorderStyle property to FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle, FormBorderStyle.Sizable, FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D, or FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog

Comment: I tried these now but unfortunately didn't work. :/

Comment: Why you mention infragistics, your form inherits from an specific Infragistics class, or direct from windows.forms??

Comment: We're using these guys here.

private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager tbmURibbon;
        private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea toolbarsDockAreaLeft;
        private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea toolbarsDockAreaRight;
        private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea toolbarsDockAreaTop;
        private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea toolbarsDockAreaBottom;

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, the controls inside your form shouldn't affect the border style, but if you are using WinFormManager it has it's own form display style